# How is this dispatch function coming from props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn from reading this app's code, and I am confused how you get dispatch from the props in this line of code:

```
 _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { email, password } = this.refs;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    dispatch(Actions.signIn(email.value, password.value));
  }
```

https://github.com/bigardone/phoenix-trello/blob/master/web/static/js/views/sessions/new.js#L17

Hoping someone can explain how calling this.props will return a dispatch?

Answer (score 1):

`const { dispatch } = this.props;` is just deconstructing `this.props.dispatch` into a `dispatch` variable so it's used from props and where do they come to props? From [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) `connect`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SessionsNew);
```

`connect` is just Higher Order Component which basically connects your component with the store. As part of this process it puts dispatch into component's `props`

Edit:

The main idea is that `connect` is a function that takes whatever components and extends it's props with dispatch property (it returns another react components that wraps your component). You can also map some properties from state to your component and bind actions with dispatch using mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps

Comment: I kind of understand, but not 100% clear what export default connect(...)(SessionNew) is doing.  Can you explain that in detail?

Comment: @coolbreeze you may find this helpful: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Comment: I think you should read more here: https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html
The main idea is that connect is a function that takes whatever components and extends it's props with dispatch property (it returns another react components that wraps your component). You can also map some properties from state to your component and bind actions with dispatch using mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps

Answer (score 1):

[react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) is a library that helps components get values from the Redux store in a predictable and performant way. The main tool it provides is a function called `connect`, which wraps Redux components providing them with store values as props. The key part of the code you link to is at the bottom: https://github.com/bigardone/phoenix-trello/blob/master/web/static/js/views/sessions/new.js#L70-L74.

Say you have a value in the Redux store named `counter`. You want your component `CounterDisplay` to know about this value, and update when it changes:

```js
class CounterDisplay extends Component {
  render () {
    const { counter, dispatch } = this.props
    return (
      <div>{counter}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Those variables are going to be undefined unless you've explicitly put the values into props the 'old fashioned way':

```js
<CounterDisplay counter={1} dispatch={() => {}} />
```

That's where `connect` comes in. It knows about the Redux store (often using another component called `Provider`) and can place values from it into the props of the component it's wrapping. It returns what's called a Higher Order Component (HOC): one that wraps another to perform a specific function, in this case connection to the store.

Here's how we'd get the `counter` value into props:

```js
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  // Slightly confusingly, here `state` means the entire application
  // state being tracked by Redux... *not* CounterDisplay's state
  return {
    counter: state.counter
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CounterDisplay)
```

So instead of exporting `CounterDisplay` itself, we export the HOC. In addition to `counter`, `connect` will also automatically insert the `dispatch` function into props so we can make use of it in the component. That's the behaviour you're seeing in the source you're reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of destructuring assignment. See more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment